# I have to refresh page for getting data in flutter listview.builder

Tags: flutter

I am fetching records from firebase collection with a UDF and calling this UDF inside Widget build,

it has to refresh to show data,

looks like. widget build before getting data....how to prevent loading widget build until data is not fetched ...

```
class _DemoPage2State extends State<DemoPage2> {

  List<String> list = [];

  void getusers() async
  {
    final snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("users").get();

    list.clear();
    for (int x = 0; x < snapshot.docs.length; x++) {
      list.add(snapshot.docs[x].id);
    }
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    getusers();
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: list.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                child: Text(list[index].toString()));
          }),

    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `StreamBuilder`

```dart
 final myStream =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").snapshots();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: StreamBuilder(
      stream: myStream,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return ListView.builder(itemBuilder: itemBuilder);
        }
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
      },
    ));
  }
```

Comment: But it will keep changes as soon as data is changed in server, I want to use list array which I made to listview.builder

Comment: try adding setState end of  for loop on `getusers`. also I dont think It is better approach calling method inside build. You can override `initState` and when you like to rebuild the list, call the method agian

Comment: Done with setState